# Adjusted regression line considering different factors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to reproduce the graph below, where the internal lines are the adjusted regression lines:

[image]

However, due to some factor, it is not being plotted what it should be, that is, a single line is being presented, and more, the different concentrations of the variable "teor" are not being plotted as in the image above, see the result below:

[image]

```
dados = read.table("datanew.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=","); head(dados)
dados$Trat <- factor(dados$Trat)
dados$Teor <- factor(dados$Teor)
dadosnew$Tempo = as.factor(dadosnew$Tempo)

my.formula <- y ~ x
p = ggplot(dadosnew, aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, group = Fator)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,  formula=y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)) + stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
                                                                                         eq.with.lhs = "As-italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
                                                                                         aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
                                                                                         parse = TRUE, size = 5, label.y = 35)+
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18,color="black"),
        text = element_text(size = 50,color="black"),
        legend.position = "none") + facet_wrap(~Fator)
p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need another grouping variable like this:

```
#Code
my.formula <- y ~ x
ggplot(dadosnew, aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, group = interaction(Fator,Trat))) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,  formula=y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,eq.with.lhs = "As-italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")),
               parse = TRUE, size = 5, label.y = 35)+
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18,color="black"),
        text = element_text(size = 50,color="black"),
        legend.position = "none") + facet_wrap(~Fator)
```

Output:

[image]

Which you, as researcher, should define.

Comment: Got the same result with `group=Teor` and `facet_wrap(~Fator)`

Comment: @YBS Yeah, it only needs to add or change the grouping variable. Many thanks!

Comment: @Duck how can i include the legend of the different lines and the points in the averages according to the times established in the desired graph in the first figure?

Comment: @BrenoG. First add a color statement in `aes()` like `color=interaction(Fator,Trat)` I will come back to you soon!

Comment: @BrenoG. Please remove these options in `theme()`: `legend.position` and `text` and you will have the legend you want. Kind regards!